# Need some help reusing an existing (java-based) IoC container for my project

Tags: java, spring, inversion-of-control

I'm working on the development of library that depends heavily on XML based configuration files. These files describe a process workflow that contains variables and references to java objects that have different scopes. An extremely simplified pseudo configuration would be:

```
<config>
    <valueProducer name="thingThatProducesAValue" class="org.com.Blah" method="foo" args="arg1, arg2" scope="application" />
    <var name="v" scope="process" value="${thingThatProducesAValue}" /> 
    <process step="somethingImportant">
        <write value="${v}" to="a_file_somewhere">
        <write value="${v}" to="a_queue">
    </process>
</config>
```

Basically this configuration defines that:
1 - an instance of the class "org.com.Blah" will be created and it will be reused while the application is running (pretty much as if it were a singleton)
2 - a variable named "v", when used somewhere, will be populated with the result of the value producer named "thingThatProducesAValue"
2.1 - the value of "v" will be evaluated once during the execution of the process "somethingImportant", and will be reused subsequently, until the end of the process.

I am looking for a java based IoC container that can be programmatically configured, and that offers some sort of support for custom management of scoped entities. I had a look on Spring but it seems very difficult do anything without using its own configuration file format or annotatinos. My requirement is to create an engine capable of reading this XML in its peculiar format and perform the value replacements and class/method invocations, but it would be great to do the essential stuff and just work on top of some library that is already available.
Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement Spring's [custom namespace handler](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/07/spring-custom-namespaces.html).